# Probability of following numbers in a sequence (parking spots problem)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to teach myself some probability and statistics (any book recommendation is more than welcome).

Here's a little problem I tried to solve and I just need some help to complete certain details. The problem goes as follows :

There's 12 aligned parking spots and 8 cars. Each car choose its spot randomly. We observe that all the 4 empty spots are following each other, is it surprising ?

My attempt :

I numbered the parking spots from 1 to 12, I then figured out how many different combination exists for the cars to park. I would say ${12 \choose 8}=495$. I then tried to count all the combinations where the empty spots are following themselves. If I now write all the empty spots down, I get :

$$ (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4,5),...,(9,10,11,12). $$

A total of 9 different combinations. So I would guess that the probability of finding a combination with the 4 empty spots following themselves is

$$ \frac{9}{495}=\frac{1}{55} \approx 0.018.$$

Is my reasoning correct ? Also I am having trouble to describe the sample space $\Omega$ for this model.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. The sample space of all possible empty spaces would be something like: $$\Omega=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4):(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)\in \mathbb N, 1\leq a_1 \lt a_2 \lt a_3 \lt a_4 \leq 12 \}$$

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: I hope not to disturb you but I thought you could maybe help me with another question I have : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663094/difference-between-conditional-probability-and-probability-of-an-intersection